# SemaphoreSlim - is it ok to use it in multiple methods to wait and release?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asp.net-core

I have an `Asp.Net Core 6 Web Api`.

I have a `Singleton` class with several methods in it.

I want only 1 thread to enter any of the methods of the class at a time.

Is it ok to initialize the `SemaphoreSlim` class in the constructor and use it in every method in the following way? Are there any dangers from it?

Is there a better way to achieve what I am looking for?

```
public class Foo
{
   private readonly SemaphoreSlim _sm;

   public Foo()
   { 
      _sm = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);
   }

   public async Task FirstMethod()
   {
      await _sm.WaitAsync();

      //Do some work
     
      _sm.Release();
   }

   public async Task SecondMethod()
   {
      await _sm.WaitAsync();

      //Do some work
     
      _sm.Release();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should adopt the `try/catch/finalize` pattern - if you do so, you're mostly safe: all code under the `WaitAsync` will be executed as defined by the max semaphore. Only if the code under the semaphore block, you'll get a deadlock - [you could consider using a timeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim.waitasync?view=net-6.0), but typically this is accepted.

```
   public async Task SecondMethod()
   {
      await _sm.WaitAsync();

      try
      {
          //Do some work
      }
      
      finally
      {
         //release in case of errors
         _sm.Release();
      }
   }
```

Other stuff to consider is, especially if it is a long running process, is to use a cancellation token to indicate application closure.

Also keep in mind that if you fire a lot of these methods from various threads, the order is not guaranteed - but they will all be handled.

Comment: This is the right answer, but I'd be concerned about leaving the `catch` out entirely. Perhaps, at minimum, `catch (Exception ex){ System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(false, ex.Message); }`

Comment: @IVSoftware it you don't know how to handle an exception, then don't handle it. Let the callers down the stack deal with the exception.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias now that I've had my 2nd cup of coffee I'd rather just retract and delete my non-useful comment if you don't mind. A `finally` block doesn't make the exception `caught` so it's fine. Occasionally, what I see in posts is an empty `catch` block and somehow it was _that_ false alarm that went off in my head. Thanks for bringing me around on that one. In my own defense, the `catch` construct that I showed _is_ useful to enforce a **Break When Thrown** if that particular exception happens to be turned off in **Exception Settings** and has saved me time e.g. when Unit Testing.